# I'm using the matlplotlib library to plot a map. I'm trying to add x label and y label to my plot but it's not showing up for some reason

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[this the plot im getting even after adding the xlabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ32E.png)Should I declare a new ax variable to set x and y labels or is there another way to get them. sorry if this seem too basic. I'm fairly new to programming

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))

min_lat = 0
max_lat = 7.5
min_lon = 99.5
max_lon = 119.5

proj = ccrs.PlateCarree();
extent = [min_lon, max_lon, min_lat, max_lat]
ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)
ax.set_extent(extent)
ax.set_xlabel("Longitude")
cm = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable()

#color bar

cbar = plt.colorbar(cm, orientation='horizontal')
cbar.set_ticks([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1])
cbar.set_ticklabels(["10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60"])
cbar.set_label('TEC (TECU)', fontsize=11, weight= BOLD)

ax.contourf(xintrp, yintrp, tecs2, norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=TEC_MIN, vmax=TEC_MAX), cmap = 'viridis', levels=80, extend='neither', zorder=3)
gl = ax.gridlines(zorder=5, color='black', alpha=0.5, draw_labels=True)

gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.xlocator = mticker.MultipleLocator(5)
gl.ylocator = mticker.MultipleLocator(5)
gl.xlabel_style = {'size': 8}
gl.ylabel_style = {'size': 8}

ax.coastlines(resolution='50m',zorder=7)
```

Comment: try to make your code runnable for others, it will help others to locate your issue. see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `set_xlabel` is in your code. does that label show up?

Comment: yes but for some reason the label is not showing up